# Only paying for an account: Is it allowed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm wondering if I can get minecraft java for a friend for free by signing into minecraft net on my account on his computer, and download it for him. Therefore, he only has to pay for a just a new account and not have to buy minecraft java as well. I'm pretty sure it works, i'm just worried that it's not allowed. Thanks!

Comment: It helps to think of it like this, even if it's not _strictly_ true: you pay for the account, not the game

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're trying to use a loophole where none exists - upon starting up Minecraft, your friend will need to log in to their account, and Minecraft: Java Edition will need to be purchased on said account in order for them to start playing the game, so there's no actual money saved.

Comment: Yep, think of it that way: the game download is free, it's the valid account with registered JE purchase that is required to play the game that you need to pay for.